# Transforming my File Type Extension from my backend in Angular?

Tags: php, angular, laravel

So I have a project where I have to build a CMS system in which users can upload their files and can see the details with it. However, the datat output I get from my database is quite complicated for regular users i.e.: image/png, application/pdf etc. From my boss, I have to change this into 'PDF', 'Video', 'Photo' etc.

However, I tried to use Angular Pipes but don't know where to begin. There's little to no documentation on how to this throught Angular pipes. Can anyone help me to transform this data to some user friendly terms?

Would be gladly appreciated!

My code:

```
<div class="GuideTable">
   <table class="table">
        <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th >Type</th>
        <th>Filename</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>Publication</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of GuidesList$.slice().reverse()">
            <th class="notbold">{{item.title}}</th>
            <th class="notbold">{{item.type}}</th>
            <th class="notbold">{{item.filename}}</th>
            <th class="notbold">{{item.date}}</th>
            <th class="notbold">{{item.source}}</th>
            <th class="notbold">{{item.role}}</th>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

My TS file:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getGuidesList().subscribe(response => {
      this.GuidesList$=response 
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt that there is lack of information on pipes. But basically pipe is a function like any other javascript function except it's executed each time binded propeties change (assuming it is a pure pipe - which it should be).

For a simple demo, let's assume `item.type` is the content type `MIME Type` that of which we will transform into something else readable - a string of `PDF, Video` etc.

This is the raname pipe, that will take `item.type` as a param, and based on `item.type` will return a string.

```js
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'rename' })
export class RenamePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(typeString: string): string {
    if (typeString === 'application/pdf') {
      return 'PDF';
    } else if (typeString === 'image/png') {
      return 'Photo';
    } else {
       return typeString
    }
  }
}
```

Html

```html
<div class="GuideTable">
  <table class="table">
       <tr>
       <th>Title</th>
       <th >Type</th>
       <th>Filename</th>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Source</th>
       <th>Publication</th>
       </tr>
       <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
           <th class="notbold">{{item.title}}</th>
           <th class="notbold">{{item.type | rename}}</th>
           <th class="notbold">{{item.filename}}</th>
           <th class="notbold">{{item.date | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</th>
           <th class="notbold">{{item.source}}</th>
           <th class="notbold">{{item.role}}</th>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
```

You can even get fancy with some prebuilt pipes like the date pipe `| date : 'dd-MM-yyyy'`

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipes-qhkh8d?file=app%2Frename.pipe.ts

---

Just a side note, in javascript we name variables in camelCase `GuidesList` -> `guidesList`. Same could go for css classes http://bdavidxyz.com/blog/how-to-name-css-classes/

We use `$` to indicate it is an observable. It's very unlikely that `getGuidesList()` returns an observable (unless your doing some funky stuff). Please also add `getGuidesList()` so we could see this part as well and refactor if necessary.

`.slice()` seems out of place and unnecessary.

If you do decide to manually `.subscribe()` then don't forget to `unsubscribe()`.

Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thank you! I have one more error though, I have a value of (0,1,2) which I transform by giving it 'if (value === 0 ) { return 'Administrator'}' But it doesn't transforms the value above (0,1,2) Any advice sir?

Comment: If you are certain that you are passing 0 number then triple equals === 0 should return true. If you are passing string "0" that will equal false, look up === as to why. Otherwise it's hard to know for sure - reproduce the problem online to diagnose.